# How to merge two images and save in php at Run Time?

Tags: php, gd

i want to make a picture upload in frame and save  both image and frame as a single image ,main thing is whatever the size of image in frame,it should be appear exactly  same in a final resulting image after merging.
Here is part of my code:

```
$imgframe = $_GET['imgframe'];
$imgphoto = $_GET['imgphoto'];

$imgwidth = $_GET['imgwidth'];
$imgheight = $_GET['imgheight'];

$imgleft = substr($_GET['imgleft'],0,-2);
$imgtop = substr($_GET['imgtop'],0, -2);

$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgphoto);//'image.jpg'
$dest = imagecreatefrompng($imgframe);//clip_image002.png

imagealphablending($dest, false);
imagesavealpha($dest, true);

imagecopyresampled( 
     $dest, $src, $imgleft, $imgtop, $imgleft, $imgtop,
     $imgwidth, $imgheight, $imgwidth, $imgheight
);
```

Comment: Have you tried any research? This is not exactly a rare topic... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+merge+images

Comment: Then what is your specific problem in doing that? Give us more details about what it is you want to know.

Comment: If I could downvote you again I would. **What is your problem in saving the image dynamically according to the size of the frame?!** Getting the size of the frame? Getting the size of the image? Doing the necessary math? Saving the image? A syntax error in your code?

Comment: while saving the final image it shows the same height as appear in frame..my problem is that  the save image should look same as in frame. but it looks snapshot of part of main image..and i want the whole image according to size..!!hope u understand..

Comment: So you need to resize the image; scale it down to the size of the frame.  How you do that depends on whether you are using the GD or Imagick API.  Please add the code you have tried to your question; people can't tell you what's wrong without seeing the code.  Also, try searching the PHP manual for the relevant API.  Finally, in order to avoid people downvoting your questions, please read [the SO guidlelines on a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [whathaveyoutried.com](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Essentially, _always post your problematic code_.

Comment: Hello diascog..i am using GD library(ImageCopymerge())for merging two images.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question showing the relevant extract from the code you have tried instead of posting it in the comments.  This will make your question clearer and also help other people who are searching for an answer to a similar problem.

Comment: Thanks for adding your code; this is now a question that can be answered.  +1 for that.

Comment: @daiscog thank you so much for instructing and guiding me.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment below the question, you are using the wrong function.

The PHP manual page for [imagecopymerge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) states that it copies a part of an image onto another.  It states that you can specify the origin coordinates, width and height of the region to copy from the source, and the coordinates in the destination in which to place that region.

In other words, it takes a rectangular area of a given size from the source image and puts it on top of the destination, at the given location.  It does NOT ask for the size of the region into which you are copying it, only the location.  Therefore, it does not resize the copied region, but copies it pixel-for-pixel.

The function you actually need is [imagecopyresampled](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php), which allows you to specify the size of the destination region, and will smoothly scale the source region to fit.

**EDIT**

You are still having a problem because you are using the same coordinates and the same dimensions in the source and the destination parameters.  Same dimensions == no resizing.

```
$imgframe = $_GET['imgframe'];
$imgphoto = $_GET['imgphoto'];

// I am assuming these specify the area of the imgphoto which
// should be placed in the frame?
$imgwidth = $_GET['imgwidth'];
$imgheight = $_GET['imgheight'];
$imgleft = substr($_GET['imgleft'],0,-2);
$imgtop = substr($_GET['imgtop'],0, -2);

// now you also need to get the size of the frame so that
// you can resize the photo correctly:
$frameSize = getimagesize($imgframe);

$src = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgphoto);//'image.jpg'
$dest = imagecreatefrompng($imgframe);//clip_image002.png

imagealphablending($dest, false);
imagesavealpha($dest, true);

imagecopyresampled( 
     $dest, $src, 
     0, 0, // these two specify where in the DESTINATION you want to place the source.  You might want these to be offset by the width of the frame
     $imgleft, $imgtop, // the origin of area of the source you want to copy
     $frameSize[0], $frameSize[1], // These specify the size of the area that you want to copy IN TO (i.e., the size in the destination), again you might want to reduce these to take into account the width of the frame
     $imgwidth, $imgheight // the size of the area to copy FROM
);
```

Comment: i have applied imagecopyresampled() but the problem is still there.

Comment: That is because you are using the same dimensions for source and destination!  See my edit above.